# Turn off virtualisation in Avalon dock

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, avalondock

When you start an app, Avalon dock will virtualise the content of a non-selected tabbed panel. It isn’t until you select the tab that the content is initially drawn (with a slight delay whilst it’s drawn). Switch tabs at that point, there is no delay

My content is a WebView2 container.

How can I ensure the content is drawn on startup and not virtualised.